# How to disable FTPloy?

Tags: git, ftp, bitbucket

I recently connected my Bitbucket account to FTPloy for easy deployment, and it worked great.  The trouble is now I need to move the repo to my team account, so I'd like to update the bitbucket account settings in FTPloy so it can connect to the new repo, but as far as I can tell there isn't anywhere on the entire site you can edit settings.  Once you've linked a repo to an FTP that's it - you don't seem to be able to edit it.

I read somewhere that for Github you have to revoke access by FTPloy from the Github side, but I can't find how to do this with Bitbucket, and even if I do manage to do it, since I can't amend the details of the old FTPloy account, do I just have to leave the FTPloy account unused and setup a new account with a new e-mail every time I want to change my FTP or Bitbucket details?  This seems ridiculous.

Hopefully I'm just being stupid and there's a nice big button somewhere under my nose that I've missed...  But if not I find it difficult to understand why anyone would offer a service that is clearly only half finished!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a nice big button under my nose - thought it was just a menu header, doh!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OP has already solved his problems. Unfortunately, that did not work for me.

I solved this by using Bitbucket Access Management settings.

Select Access Management > OAuth

In OAuth integrated applications page, you should be able to see a list of authorized apps. You can revoke access for each app there.

[image]

Comment: But you would still need to update FTPloy to point to your new bitbucket repo, which is what this question was about :)

Comment: Yes, need to set new repo. But I guess at least part of your problems solved. I also agree that features are really limited there.

Comment: We moved to deployhq and haven't looked back :)